# Getting help in complicated query for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

having this piece of schema

```
Doctor(licence_no, doctor_name, specialty)

Patient(pat_id, pat_name, pat_address, pat_phone, date_of_birth)

Visit(licence_no, pat_id, date, type, diagnosis, charge)
```

and i want to get the names of all patients who visited all doctors
i did it as follows

```
SELECT p.pat_name FROM Patient p

INNER JOIN Visit v ON (v.pat_ID = p.pat_ID)

INNER JOIN Doctor d ON (d.licence_no = v.licence_no)

WHERE (SELECT d.licence_no FROM Doctor d) = (SELECT v.licence_no FROM Visit v2 WHERE 

p.pat_ID =v.pat_ID)
```

but there is an error as the sub query returns more than 1 value and i have to make sure that this patient had visited all doctors, any suggestions to make this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be sure that a patient has visited all doctors, you can compare a distinct count of doctors (`license_no`) to the counts of `license_no` grouped by `pat_id` in `Visit`.

Something like this may do the job:

```
SELECT pat_name
FROM Patient p JOIN Visit v ON p.pat_id = v.pat_id
GROUP BY v.pat_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.license_no) = (SELECT COUNT(license_no) FROM Doctor);
```

The idea here is merely to verify that if there are, for example 5 doctors in `Doctor`, the patient has visited 5 distinct doctors in `Visit`.

This is, of course, untested.